# how to use Credential wallet path with metamask account on infura in Web3j

Tags: java, android, web3-java

Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService());  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
    Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("password", "/path/to/walletfile");

1. How to connect rinkeby network using Web3j.
2. I try to change `"/path/to/walletfile"` by a private key of metamask account. Without success.

How can I make it works?
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do this is using your private key. In metamask click "account details" and "export private key".

Then use `Credentials.create("YourPrivateKey")`